# Know how many lines or space are left until the end of the page in MS-Word

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

I need to know, when I insert text into a word document, how many lines or space I have left until I reach the bottom of the page.

My problem is that I am writing records (a bold title and lines of text) from a database. Sometimes, a title remains on the current page and the text on the next one. And I want to prevent this from happening, by inserting a page break. To perform this page break, I must know how much space or lines I have left before the end of the page.

Is there any way to know how many lines or how much space is left until the end of the page?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try something very complicated (and unnecessary) like 'counting how much space or lines are left before the end of the page'. The definition that you need is in the 'paragraph' palette - in the 'line and page breaks' window, there is an option called 'keep with next'. This option will bump the chosen line (the title) to the next page if there is not enough room on the same page for the text which belongs to the title.

In a macro, it looks like Selection.ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext = True